# How to add meta box to specific page?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I am trying to add meta boxes in the WordPress back-end only to a specific page. With a hook it is possible to display text just on the specific page. The `echo 'test';` in my code is working right, but the meta boxes appear in all pages in the back-end. I really don't understand, the conditional statement seems to work right, what is my mistake?

```
$metabox_frontpage = include 'metabox_frontpage.php';

function add_metabox_frontpage() {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    if ( $post->ID == 62 ) {
        echo 'test';
        echo $metabox_frontpage;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'add_metabox_frontpage' );
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the barebones of `metabox_frontpage.php`. Are you doing this Gutenberg style?

Comment: I am not doing it the Gutenberg style. I don't think that the problem is on the metabox_frontpage.php, because if I do the include outside of a function it is working without problems. The code above is also adding the metabox, but on all pages. The echo 'test' appears only on the page with the id 62, but the metabox appears on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
function my_meta_init() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    if ($post_id == '62' || $post_id == '66' || $post_id == '68'){
        include 'metabox_frontpage.php';
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');
```